# Do a substantial number of born-again American Christians not believe "that Jesus bodily came back to life"?

Tags: christianity, jesus-christ

In Dan Barker's *Godless: How an Evangelical Preacher Became One of
America's Leading Atheists,* at the start of Chapter Sixteen, he writes
(emphasis mine):

> Many bible scholars[25] and ministers—including one third of the clergy
> in the Church of England[26]—reject the idea that Jesus bodily came back
> to life. *So do 30 percent of born-again American Christians!*[27]

Is it really true that 30 percent of born-again American Christians answer
"no" to a survey asking if they agree that Jesus "bodily" came back to life?

Note that I am *not* asking what doctrine (in general, or for any
particular denomination) is; I am asking *how people reply* to the
question.

Below I try to address several issues that have come up in the extensive
comments on this question as well as provide what evidence I have so far.

**Please note:** I see that many of the comments are about the details of
the definitions of certain terms. I would like to suggest that this is not
a very productive line to go down and instead we should focus on the
*evidence we can find* and consider whether the definitions used by that
evidence are a problem only if the definitions seem terribly out of line
with what Barker appears to be using.

**Question Forum**

How people reply to the question above on a survey is something that can be
supported or disconfirmed from modern evidence, and such a survey can be
replicated for further support (or disconfirmation). Thus I am posting in
this forum, which is for ["researching the evidence behind the claims you
hear or read"](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable). Note that this question does not resemble any of the
numerous examples given in ["What types of questions can I ask on this
site?"](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409) for the Christianity StackExchange.

**Definition of "Bodily Resurrection"**

Regarding the definition of "bodily came back to life," it's clear from
context that Barker is talking not about a [spiritual body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritual_body) but the
actual physical body:

> When the Gospel of John portrays the postmortem Jesus on a fishing trip
> with his buddies and the writer of Matthew shows him giving his team a
> mountaintop pep talk two days after he died, how can there be any doubt
> that the original believers were convinced he had bodily risen from the
> grave?...
>
> The earliest Christians believed in the “spiritual” resurrection of
> Jesus. The story evolved over time into a “bodily” resurrection.

Unfortunately, without the original source I do not know what the exact
question asked in the survey was, nor am I qualified to determine how the
respondents would have interpreted that question. However, Barker has
extensive training in Evangelical theology so it seems unlikely that he's
misunderstanding what he's writing, and likely that he was able to properly
understand and interpret the survey question and answers.

**Definition of "Born Again"**

It is clear that there are Christians who are ["born again"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_again) and
those who are not; that Wikipeda page identifies denominations that fall
into this category and Barker gives an example (the Church of England)
which is not. There's obviously a spectrum where there's room for argument
in the middle but, as with "left wing" and "right wing," that does not mean
that the distinction does not exist. I am not terribly concerned about the
details of how the distinction is made in surveys or other evidence so long
as it's not obviously vastly different from the common definitions.

**Evidence from Barker**

The footnote given for reference [27] in the quote above is,

> “Americans’ Bible Knowledge Is in the Ballpark, But Often Off Base,” July
> 12, 2000, Barna Research Group.

I've found the [Barna Research Group website](https://www.barna.com/), but I cannot find this
study in a search on that site, nor does it appear in their [chronological
listing of research](https://www.barna.com/research/page/42/).

**Evidence from Elsewhere**

In a comment Kyralessa offers another Barna study, ["Most Americans Take
Well-Known Bible Stories at Face Value"](https://www.barna.com/research/most-americans-take-well-known-bible-stories-at-face-value/). On the face of it this
seems to disconfirm Barker's statement: the surveyed rate of belief in
bodily resurection for all denominations is considerably higher (85%) than
Barker quotes for even born again (70%) much less non-born again (one third
for Church of England) and for "non-mainline Protestants" (which presumably
has a higher proportion of born-again Christians) it's 95%.

Comment: I think they all agree Jesus was resurrected, the question is whether he had a flesh-and-blood body, or whether it was something more transformative. This goes back to the Gospels. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection_of_Jesus?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Who defines who the "born-again" Christians are? It's a label anyone can self-identify as, but rejecting the resurrection of Jesus would exclude you from almost all churches' definitions of real born-again Christians.

Comment: "reject the idea that Jesus bodily came back to life" - Is this the same as not believing in resurrection or is this more like having a separate definition of resurrection?

Comment: @JeromeViveiros It appears that it could be either: believing in the resurrection of just a "spiritual body" or not believing in it at all. Regardless, my question is about belief that the physical body was resurrected, not just a "spiritual body." I've edited the question to (I hope) make this more clear.

Comment: The claim here seems to boil down to "different Christian denominations, and individual scholars and believers, have different interpretations of the Bible", which shouldn't really surprise anyone. Other than tracking down that one source and its vague notion of "born-again American Christians", this feels like it might be better addressed on a Christianity site, something like: "What are the different interpretations of the resurrection among Christians?"

Comment: @IMSoP No. Especially considering the author's background (he's an ex-Evangelical Preacher) I am fairly sure he is using "born-again" specifically to mean Evangelical and similar denominations that have this as a [core doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_again). Note that he explicitly distinguishes born-again denominations from the C of E (where it does _not_ surprise me that many do not believe in the bodily resurrection).

Comment: As for venue, I feel that Skeptics is a better place to post requests to track down factual information. I'm interested in reported beliefs from reliable surveys, whereas Christianity sites seem more likely to produce answers about what born-again Christians are _supposed_ to believe, rather than what they _do_ believe, especially when the two are inconsistent.

Comment: I guess I'm just missing a lot of context here then, which should perhaps be added to the question. As written, it doesn't mention any particular denomination, or why this belief would be more surprising among them than anyone else. That Wikipedia link doesn't really help either, mentioning a whole list of denominations, and unrelated to Christ's resurrection. On the other hand, maybe I'm just not the right audience for this question, and this is all blindingly obvious to others.

Comment: @IMSoP The quote directly mentions the Church of England, which is a well known denomination (at least amongst people I know). "Born again" seemed to me to cover a fairly obvious set of denominations, and Wikipedia confirmed this (I gave the link in my previous comment). I perceive those denominations to be fairly fundamentalist and would expect them to have literal beliefs, and Barker appears to have the same expectation. Regardless, the question can be answered factually (if the data exist) without concern about whether I'm correct or not to be surprised.

Comment: Right, that falls into my "on the other hand" then: to me, none of that is obvious. The C of E is officially the established church here, but I honestly have no idea what their official doctrine says about the resurrection, and whether there's room for difference on how "bodily" it happened. I know even less about American Evangelicals.

Comment: I can't find the original Barna study (from 22 years ago), but here's something a bit more recent which discusses the resurrection: https://www.barna.com/research/most-americans-take-well-known-bible-stories-at-face-value/

Comment: There are two issues here. 1.) Was the resurrection to a physical body, or to a spirit body that was capable of physical manifestation. 2.) How knowledgeable are "born again" Christians. ¶ The first question is for scholars, and mostly not  relevant to the common person. The second question can easily be answered: most "born again" Christians have very emotional beliefs and know only a very small fraction of the doctrines of their faith. [Americans know Big Macs better than Ten Commandments | Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-bible-commandments-idUSN1223894020071012).

Comment: @RayButterworth You appear to be positing 1) as a question about official doctrine, and of course 2) is related to that. I'm interested in neither; I simply want to know how born-again American Christians _reply_ to the first question, regardless of the official doctrine of their denomination.

Comment: Here is [another Barna article](https://www.barna.com/research/state-church-2016/) which contains a definition of "Born Again" separate from "Evangelical". It's from 2016, so their definition made have changed. "***Born again***: *Have made a personal commitment to Jesus Christ that is still important in their life today and believe that, when they die, they will go to heaven because they have confessed their sins and accepted Jesus Christ as their savior.*" "***Evangelical Christian***: *Meet the born again criteria plus seven other conditions...*" (too long for comment).

Comment: If it question is simply about the beliefs of Born Again Christians about a theological debate over the resurrection, I would agree Christianity.SE would be a better venue. This debate has been going on for 2000 years.

Comment: Are you just looking for the original survey? That doesn't really seem to fit the purpose of Skeptics.SE very well. These sorts of results of the form "religious folk who say they adhere to a given faith either disagree with/misunderstand/interpret differently some aspect of their faith" are common; for faiths that tolerate it, their leaders often have these arguments openly with one another. What is there to be skeptical about here?

Comment: @BryanKrause No, I'm looking for good data on the question. Not having seen it, I'm not even sure if the original survey provides that ), but other data would do just fine anyway. Barker makes a pretty clear claim about fact that can be supported or disconfirmed through evidence; that seems to be exactly ["researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read"](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable). I will update the question to try to make this more clear.

Comment: I don't think it's really a "claim about fact", he's just citing a survey.

Comment: @BryanKrause He is stating a claim as a fact, with the survey as supporting evidence. This is very different from "survey says X; I'm not saying that's true." The claim is clearly one can be supported or disconfirmed by direct evidence: if the original survey is correct it should be able to be replicated. If no similar surveys have been made, we can at least look to see if the original survey methodology and interpretation is reasonable (assuming we can find the original data).

Comment: I have extensively rewritten the question to try to focus on evidence, rather than discussion of definitions. I would encourage everyone making further comments to consider whether their comment is going towards _finding evidence_ or is merely engaging in discussion about definitions or the merits of the question.

Comment: Despite editing, the big problem is 'born again' and even 'Christian'. Anyone can self-identify who has no affiliation with any gathering, but how could they, then, be surveyed ? There is ***no way** that Dan Barker can prove his claim - which is why he does not provide proper references.  _Anecdotal_ reference is not _evidence_.

Comment: @NigelJ The reference is not "anecdotal"; it's evidence, of unknown quality, to which we don't have access. (Or Barker was lying about the existence of the poll; if you think he's making up things out of whole cloth, you could bring up the evidence you have that this is the likely case.) As for the definitions, again, show the definitions in _any_ survey and tell me why you think they do or do not match this question. Your opinion that this is hard to define or subject to argument does not contribute to increasing knowledge; we already knew that.